# Magento get thumbnail image url to be displayed on cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I having problem in getting the thumbnail image url for the items on the Magento Cart

Here is my code:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
echo $item->getThumbnail();
}
```

Does anyone know that why does it returns always blank.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
```

Will do the trick

Comment: This gets the image of the Configurable Product. Do you know how to get the image of the Associated Product?

Comment: can you please answe @Klevis question, as I am too facing the same issue.